# setting a variable in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, 2d-games

Currently designing a game and the idea is that of a high score, so that when the current score is more than the local storage one it is replaced:

```js
localStorage.setItem('highScore', highScore);
var HighScore = localStorage.getItem('highScore');
if (HighScore == null || HighScore == "null") {
  HighScore = 0;
}

if (user.points > HighScore) {
  highScore = parseInt(HighScore);
}
return highScore
```

Thanks guys

Comment: you cannot do `setItem` first, that will overwrite whatever was stored in the first place

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 18):

This should point you in the correct direction.

```js
// Get Item from LocalStorage or highScore === 0
var highScore = localStorage.getItem('highScore') || 0;

// If the user has more points than the currently stored high score then
if (user.points > highScore) {
  // Set the high score to the users' current points
  highScore = parseInt(user.points);
  // Store the high score
  localStorage.setItem('highScore', highScore);
}

// Return the high score
return highScore;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what I think you are trying to achieve. Of course this is just an example and not the code written for you.

```
<button id="save10">Save 10</button>
<button id="save12">Save 12</button>

var highscore = 11,
    button10 = document.getElementById("save10"),
    button12 = document.getElementById("save12"),
    savedHighscore;

function saveData(x) {
    localStorage.setItem('highscore', x);
}

button10.addEventListener("click", function () {
    saveData(10);
}, false);

button12.addEventListener("click", function () {
    saveData(12);
}, false);

savedHighscore = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('highscore'), 10);
if (typeof savedHighscore === "number" && highscore <  savedHighscore) {
    highscore = savedHighscore;
}

alert("Highscore: " + highscore);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ps4Qc/)

Use the buttons to set the highscore, either 10 or 12. Refresh page, or hit run(only simulates a refresh). The user always scores 11 and it will alert either 11 or 12 depending on the saved highscore.