# JavaScript maintain count value on page reload

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, if `.blink` is clicked `.nclicks` is counted. But on reloading the page the value of `.nclicks` returns back to `0` .I would like to maintain the number of clicks reached even after reload. How do I do that??

```
<p>clicks <a id="nclicks">0</a></p>
<a href="#" class="blink" onclick="countv();return false;" >true</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
var nclicks = 0;
function countv() {
    nclicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("nclicks").innerHTML = nclicks + '';
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Client-side only, you need localStorage.

See this thread :

[setting a variable in local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245536/setting-a-variable-in-local-storage)